Is it possible that converting a document from PNG to PDF using ConvertAPI will reduce the quality of the document?
I have my own code for converting docs to PDF, however, the process makes the doc pixelated and less clear, wondering if CovertApi will solve this.
(I cannot verify this since these are random cases)
Do you have experience using this particular code? I would be happy to consult.

Depends on whatever your own code is doing, and the source being converted.  Please share details, and tell us what "CovertApi" is (or do you mean: ConvertApi )

Talking about this service site: https://www.convertapi.com/. Thanks!
Regardless of what my own code is doing, I want to replace it completely.

For the **pixelated ** you could do some research on DPI  (like: How to figure out the resolution (DPI) of images embedded in a PDF document? ) higher DPI's are less pixelated...

I am looking for someone who has tried the above service and can tell me if they encountered a scenario where the quality of the document got damaged by the conversion.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
